# Multiple top panels popping up in the same screen

Tags: display

When I connect a monitor to my laptop, multiple top panels seem to be popping up in my laptop screen, one on top of the other, like in the picture. Is there any solution for this?

[image]

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 tirtha tirtha 4096 মার্চ  28 02:43 .  
drwx------  3 tirtha tirtha 4096 মার্চ  28 02:33 ..  
drwxrwxr-x  5 tirtha tirtha 4096 জুলাই  31  2019 disconnect-wifi@kgshank.net  
drwxrwxr-x  3 tirtha tirtha 4096 জুলাই  31  2019 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com  
drwxrwxr-x  4 tirtha tirtha 4096 জুলাই  31  2019 extra-panels@darkxst.feathertop.org  
drwxrwxr-x  7 tirtha tirtha 4096 নভেম্ব  5 15:06 gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io  
drwxrwxr-x  4 tirtha tirtha 4096 আগস্ট  20  2019 hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca  
drwxrwxr-x  2 tirtha tirtha 4096 আগস্ট  20  2019 hide-top-panel@dimka665.gmail.com  
drwxrwxr-x  4 tirtha tirtha 4096 নভেম্ব  5 15:08 tweaks-system-menu@extensions.gnome-shell.fifi.org  
drwxrwxr-x  3 tirtha tirtha 4096 জুলাই  31  2019 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 জুলাই  25  2018 .  
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 জানু   18 10:42 ..  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 জুলাই  25  2018 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 জুলাই   2  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Looks like a GNOME Shell extension problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and turn off ALL extensions, restart GNOME Shell or reboot, and see if your problem is gone. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @hynnema
I tried turning off all extensions in extensions.gnome.org/local, but it didn't work

Comment: Did you restart GNOME Shell, or reboot? Show me the `ls` commands that I asked for earlier.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LwtGL0xxFPTbtygcBp_-uR8EmbM7AxhK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: These are the list from the ls commands, sorry I'm new at this, couldn't post a photo in the comment and the list was long. And yes, I rebooted my computer after turning off the extensions, still didn't work

Comment: Rather than a google drive document (which I'd rather not download to see it), please edit your question, copy/paste the `ls` output, select the pasted text, then hit the `{}` icon to format it. Also show me a current screenshot.

Comment: Have you put a custom theme/icons on your computer? If so, try using the standard theme/icons and see if that helps.

Comment: @hynnema please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a GNOME Shell extension problem, or a theme/icon problem.

Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local and turn off ALL extensions, restart GNOME Shell or reboot, and see if your problem is gone.

You indicate that this didn't solve the problem. However, I see at least three extensions that could cause your problem...

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 tirtha tirtha 4096 জুলাই  31  2019 extra-panels@darkxst.feathertop.org  
drwxrwxr-x  4 tirtha tirtha 4096 আগস্ট  20  2019 hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca  
drwxrwxr-x  2 tirtha tirtha 4096 আগস্ট  20  2019 hide-top-panel@dimka665.gmail.com
```

Delete these extensions, and then restart GNOME Shell, or reboot.